# index 0 beyond bounds for empty array' *** First throw call stack:

Tags: ios, iphone, nsarray

I'm getting the error like below plz help me Advance Thanks, This is the error iam getting index 0 beyond bounds for empty array' *** First throw call stack:--->>
Below is my code:

```
-(void)retriveContactsFromAddressBook
{
    //CFErrorRef error = NULL;
     ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

    if (addressBook!=nil)
    {
        NSArray *allContacts=(__bridge_transfer NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
        NSUInteger i=0;
        for ( i = 0; i<[allContacts count]; i++)
        {
            ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];
             NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
            NSString *lastName=(__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

            if (i==0) {
                self.FirstName=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:firstName];
                if (lastName==nil) {
                    self.LastName=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                } else {
                    self.LastName=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:lastName];
                }

            } else {
                [self.FirstName addObject:firstName];

                if (lastName==nil) {
                    [self.LastName addObject:@""];
                } else {
                     [self.LastName addObject:lastName];
                }
            }
            NSString *full=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[self.FirstName objectAtIndex:i],[self.LastName objectAtIndex:i]];

            if (i==0) {
                self.fullName=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:full];
            } else {
                [self.fullName addObject:full];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error Address book empty");
    }
}
```

I'm getting error like below---->>>

```
>Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x2ce265f7 0x3a560c77 0x2cd3a157 0x126419 0x125edb 0x125cb7 0x302ce46d 0x30378325 0x3037824d 0x303777d1 0x3037750b 0x30377271 0x30377209 0x302cb97f 0x2fcf6f65 0x2fcf2951 0x2fcf27d9 0x2fcf21c7 0x2fcf1fd1 0x2fcebedd 0x2cded015 0x2cdea6f9 0x2cdeaafb 0x2cd37b31 0x2cd37943 0x340f0051 0x3032d6f1 0x1e1ea9 0x3aafcaaf)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
    (lldb)
```

Comment: In the case where i=0 and last name is nil you allocate a new NSMutableArray but don't put anything in it. You then try and access the first element to build the full name - you should add an empty string as you do for the case where i>0

Comment: See `[self.FirstName objectAtIndex:i]` & `[self.LastName objectAtIndex:i]` lines. Have you checked that both contains some values?

Comment: can u tell me clearly plzzz..@paulw

Comment: hear [self.FirstName objectAtIndex:i] the i value is showing "0" @Kampai

Comment: What about `self.LastName` array? Does it contains any value?

Comment: thxq for helping got it

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; tableViewCell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; tableViewCell.accessoryView.hidden = YES; self.selectedUsers=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.phoneNumber[indexPath.row],nil]; NSLog(@"selected users:%@",self.phoneNumber);

Comment: iam getting selected user is nill ?

Comment: help me out plzz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060309/when-i-select-some-selected-user-from-my-tableview-it-showing-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)retriveContactsFromAddressBook
{
    //CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

    self.LastName=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.FirstName=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.fullName=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:full];

    if (addressBook!=nil)
    {
        NSArray *allContacts=(__bridge_transfer NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
        NSUInteger i=0;
        for ( i = 0; i<[allContacts count]; i++)
        {
            ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];
            NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
            NSString *lastName=(__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

            if (firstName == nil) {
                [self.FirstName addObject:@""];
            } else {
                [self.FirstName addObject:firstName];
            }

            if (lastName==nil) {
                [self.LastName addObject:@""];
            } else {
                [self.LastName addObject:lastName];
            }

            NSString *full=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[self.FirstName objectAtIndex:i],[self.LastName objectAtIndex:i]];

            [self.fullName addObject:full];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error Address book empty");
    }
}
```

Use like this..

```
self.LastName=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

This line is the problem.. If lastname is nil you didn't insert any object

```
NSString *full=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[self.FirstName objectAtIndex:i],[self.LastName objectAtIndex:i]];
```

But in this line `[self.LastName objectAtIndex:i]` you try to retrieve object from the empty array that is problem...

Comment: help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060309/when-i-select-some-selected-user-from-my-tableview-it-showing-null

Answer (score 0):

Nayeemuddin you are accessing an array with no contents in it, so the exception is occurring.

```
NSString *full=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[self.FirstName objectAtIndex:i],[self.LastName objectAtIndex:i]];
```

here you are accessing object of an array which does not exists.
Also you forgot to initialise second array ,

```
 self.LastName=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert a null entry into the last name array when you allocate it.

```
for ( i = 0; i<[allContacts count]; i++)
{
            ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];
             NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
            NSString *lastName=(__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

            if (i==0) {
                self.FirstName=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:firstName];
                if (lastName==nil) {
                    self.LastName=[[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:@""];  // <--- This
                } else {
                    self.LastName=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:lastName];
                }

            } else {
                [self.FirstName addObject:firstName];

                if (lastName==nil) {
                    [self.LastName addObject:@""];
                } else {
                     [self.LastName addObject:lastName];
                }
            }
```

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    tableViewCell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    tableViewCell.accessoryView.hidden = YES;
     self.selectedUsers=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.phoneNumber[indexPath.row],nil];
    NSLog(@"selected users:%@",self.phoneNumber);

Comment: iam getting selected user is nill ??

Comment: Then I guess you have never initialised `self.phoneNumber`

Comment: wher i have to initislise it help me

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    tableViewCell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    tableViewCell.accessoryView.hidden = YES;
    
    self.phoneNumber=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:@" "];
    self.selectedUsers=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.phoneNumber[indexPath.row],nil];
    NSLog(@"selected users:%@",self.phoneNumber);

Comment: I guess in `retrieveContactsFromAddressBook` - just as you do with the names arrays

Comment: help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060309/when-i-select-some-selected-user-from-my-tableview-it-showing-null